# Como ajustar as view para que fiquem pequenas independente do dispositivo?

Tags: java, android

Fiz uma aplicação onde crio parte da interface em xml e parte via código java, a parte em xml funciona em qualquer aplicação adaptando certinho o tamanho da tela. A parte via código em um dispositivo de 7,8 polegadas fica bom, porém em uma tela de 4 polegadas fica todo desconfigurado (fonte das  views gigante). Já pesquisei muito na internet e nada funciona. Alguém sabe o que posso fazer? Agradeço desde já.

Tentei usar esse código mas não funcionou:

```
tv2.setTextSize(20 * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().scaledDensity);
```

Comment: Esse código que postou é que pode gerar esse problema. Se estiver a usar sempre `tv2.setTextSize(20);` então o problema está noutro sitio. Coloque o código onde cria essas views.

Comment: eu só uso TextView nesta aplicação, se eu colocar setTextSize(x) também da problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se o problema for apenas o tamanho das fontes, vc pode utilizar o seguinte para solucionar o seu problema.

Primeiro deve determinar em qual dispositivo está executando a sua aplicação.

```
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

    int widthPixels = metrics.widthPixels;
    int heightPixels = metrics.heightPixels;

    float scaleFactor = metrics.density;

    float widthDp = widthPixels / scaleFactor;
    float heightDp = heightPixels / scaleFactor;

    float smallestWidth = Math.min(widthDp, heightDp);
```

Após descobrir o valor de smallestWidth vc pode determinar se está executando a aplicação em um tablet de 7, 10 polegadas ou em um smartphone e ajustar o tamanho do texto de acordo.

```
// tamanho para smartphone
int size = 10

if (smallestWidth > 720) {
    //tablet de 10"
    size = 20

} else if (smallestWidth > 600) {
    //tablet de 7"
    size = 15
}
```

Após determinar o tamanho vc pode configurar sua view.

```
tv2.setTextSize(size)
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Resposta adaptada [daqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15055458/detect-7-inch-and-10-inch-tablet-programmatically).

Comment: Obrigado. Exatamente o que eu precisava.